# How can I change the "Privacy & Terms" link in recaptcha

Tags: javascript, css, customization, recaptcha

I am using Recaptcha in my site and I was wondering if it is possible to change or even delete the link on the clean theme that says "Privacy & Terms".

```
   Recaptcha.create(publicKey, "recaptcha_div",
        {
            theme: 'clean',
            lang: 'en',
            callback: callback
        }
    );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as Im aware, this would break the terms of use so you shouldnt remove

Comment: I want to customize it because of different languages, so I would like at least to be able to change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work just fine.

```
span#recaptcha_privacy {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also enter a custom [translation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization):

```
custom_translations : {
    instructions_visual : "Scrivi le due parole:",
    instructions_audio : "Trascrivi ci\u00f2 che senti:",
    play_again : "Riascolta la traccia audio",
    cant_hear_this : "Scarica la traccia in formato MP3",
    visual_challenge : "Modalit\u00e0 visiva",
    audio_challenge : "Modalit\u00e0 auditiva",
    refresh_btn : "Chiedi due nuove parole",
    help_btn : "Aiuto",
    incorrect_try_again : "Scorretto. Riprova.",
    privacy_and_terms : "Anything you want or empty"
}
```

The last variable is not in the documentation but works fine.